# How to plot two columns in a dataframe and add legends?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

i have a question in pandas plotting.  I have a dataframe that contains 4 columns.  How do i plot just two columns and add legends?  The column names are actlow,acthigh,fcstlow,fcsthigh
so for instance...i want to do this:

```
    pd.DataFrame.plot(['fcstlow','fcsthigh'],legend=True)
```

Above statement doesn't really plot the legends which is annoying me.  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((4,3)), columns=list('ABC'))
for col in ('A', 'B'):
    df[col].plot(legend=True)
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]